# all VBA usnig office 2003 applications fail to start (in windows10)

Tags: vba

Since a good 6 weeks, none of my office (2003) applications containing VBA modules will start. They all crash (in fact: immediately close without any message) when starting them.
Several MDBs, working without problems since 20years (or less), with extensive VBA coding: they all close upon starting.
Several Word applications close abruptly when any of the contained macros is invoked. One of these (a trial) has only *sub document_open () msgbox "xxx" end sub* placed in *ThisDocument*
An inherited excel application containing VBA code also closes abruptly upon starting.
Tried in administrator mode, same result.
ALL these application work perfectly on two other windows 10 PC's in my household.
So, it ain't the coding!
ALL these PC's are up to date on win 10.
Any ideas? Anyone?

Comment: i would start by reinstaling Office...

Comment: Thanks. Done that. No change. I'm thinking it miqht be a problem in my Windows updates. Ran SFC, no effect …